Checking the build of each executable, disassembling all the .o files. How to hunt down the xz kind of backdoor elsewhere in Linux distributions?
You might have read about the backdoor that was released with the xz command (versions 5.6.0 and 5.6.1).
A malevolent committer gained the trust of his maintainer, and achieved to insert at build time some code that is targeting sshd and creates a backdoor.
Other .o files of any Linux distribution can be also affected with the same kind of backdoor.
What a malevolent committer has successfully done here, he can have done it elsewhere. And maybe years ago...
How should the designers of a Linux distribution,
if they are willing to to wipe out such backdoor,
should proceed to find any corrupted executable of this kind (made by a diverted build process)?
At this moment, the ways I see are:

to check every build process of every Linux command created:
it's a lot of git repository to check, I think

but also, disassemble every existing .o file
and have a look to their assembly code, to see if it's coherent with what that executable is supposed to do.


What other ways should they use to hunt down this backdoor everywhere it can be?

Your 2. option is unfeasible, and necessarily includes the 1. option. How do you know what "what it's supposed to do" is? Right, what the source code says it should do; disassembly of modern byte/machine code, however, looks pretty much nothing like the original C/C++/rust/… code that was used to produce it, for good reason. You can't disassemble libreoffice calc and see that it's a spreadsheet editor component to an office suit, and that the "sort by date" function does this and that within an hour – figuring out something very simple takes hours and a lot of experience and tooling, no way you do that with a whole library as complex as liblzma, and not in a hundred years with something as complicated as firefox.
So you need to check the other direction: is the machine code I get really the truthful translation of the reviewed source code?
How do you translate from source code to machine code in object files? Right, you run the compiler. How do you run the compiler? With the project's build system.
And that is exactly what got attacked in the first place.
So, the only way out to "see" where things are inserted is an intense review of the whole code tree, with human code– and domain-knowledge on what that is. You need essentially the people that developed something to explain it to you while you check it. There's another feasibility, and another trust problem, right there! And note that the insertion of the evil code happened in the modified M4 code of the build system – a language that is known to everyone, including the authors of the build system to be so cryptic that nobody really understands it and copies around other people's code.
What can you do, automatedly? When you look at what that exploit does when loaded is that it modifies what a function in a completely different software than the backdoored library does. Detecting that is not trivial at all – because we do that all the time in software: every time your program loads a shared object, the initialization functions in that shared object are executed, and in the end, you end up with the library initialized, whatever that means, and entries in a table filled out, which convert the symbols (i.e., the function names used from that library) to addresses of functions. That's, in a nutshell, dynamic linking.
Now, what this hack very elegantly did was mess around in other symbols that aren't even their own. That is sad, but we currently have no good protections against that, partially because a lot of functionality depends on it – from plugin APIs to runtime dispatchers (like the GCC ifunc feature, which you probably have read about in the context of all this). Note that all these things can be implemented however you feel like.
For example, I'm moderately involved in a library that contains vector-optimized math kernels, in hand-optimized and compiler-optimized versions for different processors (think "for anything that is a target for a C compiler", "for x86 that supports MMX", "for x86_64 that supports AVX2", "for aarch64 + NEON", "for PPC with altivec", … and combinations thereof). But there's not an implementation for everything! So you might need to fall back onto the "plain C" implementation in some cases.
Now, the function that a consumer of that calls is something like multiply_two_vectors(float* out, const float* vec1, const float* vec2, int num); not multiply_two_vectors_on_CPU_with_MMX_SSE_SSE2_SSSE3_AVX_AVX2(…), yet the library "magically" picks the fastest implementation for your CPU, at no additional runtime overhead. How? Its initialization function goes in, takes the values from a benchmarked table that identify the best implementation, and puts the address of the fastest function into the table where multiply_two_vectors is. That's all. One could have implemented the same with GCC ifunc, but then we'd only work on systems with GCC – on Linux, but not on Linux systems that compile with clang, nor on Mac OS, nor on some other BSDs, nor on Windows, nor on IBM zOS, nor with intel ICC… serious problem for this library.
So, like many other libraries, we do our own dispatch in the initialization. So, initialization functions that modify symbol table entries to bend what gets executed are quite a common sight. But that initialization, and the fact that things can get bent, are part of what enabled this exploit. So, neither looking for ifunc usage nor custom shared object file initializers in itself will give you a guarantee that something is fishy – in fact, that code is in most cases auto-generated by the compiler, and might itself be optimized for some use cases.
The problem goes further: all these modifications, they could also have been done in totally normal library code. Instead of in the initializer, my library might just check in the multiply_two_vectors function whether it has already patched the process it runs in, and if it wants, replace all calls to printf with printf("chickens!\n") or do whatever nefarious thing it wants to do. The problem would then indeed be that it might touch parts of the program space at times where it's not usual to touch them, but that's also a very heuristic realization, and not easily converted to a ecosystem-wide analysis. What if the modification only happens when the one function gets called that really only something that happens to process SSH data needs, if someone sends a packet that is exactly 133700 bytes long after decompression? You can't "accidentally" trigger that behaviour.
And in fact, malware does a lot, usually, to evade behavioural detection; for example, a lot of viruses will just do nothing if they detect a debugger being attached to the current process, or them running in a VM (if they target desktop users, at least), or if the IP addresses of the device they run on do not indicate they're run on an Iranian uranium gas centrifuge (remember stuxnet!).
So, there's not "one thing" that you'll find that could be recommended to distros. Of course, "take good care to ship only code that you have read and trust" is a nice thing to say, but that's what they hope to do, ideally, anyways, and it's still unattainable.
In this case, the exploit was only in the tarball, not in the upstream git repo. So, "don't use tar balls, use the git repo!" is another nice recommendation, but some distros prefer and require tarballs, because they don't want to rely on developers not removing a git hash that happened to be what the last package build was based on. It's a double-edged sword!
